# Check GPS with Google Maps Android Studio

Tags: android, gps, google-maps-api-2

Well, I basically want that, I want to be able  to check if the GPS is enabled while I'm using the maps, I have this code, but I don't know where to check it so it does it always:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

   // LocationManager manager=(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
       /* if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Holap", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }*/


    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }


    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
       /* if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }*/
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }


    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Con Sus",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        habilitarGPS();
    }


    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Con Fail",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    habilitarGPS();
    }


    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        comprobargps();
        if (mLastLocation!=location) {
            mLastLocation = location;
            if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
                mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
            }

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title("Current Position");

            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
            mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            //Para mover la cámara
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

            if (mGoogleApiClient!=null) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            }
        }
    }


    /**************************************************************/

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        habilitarGPS();
    }

    public void habilitarGPS(){
        AlertDialog hey=cuadro();
        hey.show();
    }

    public AlertDialog cuadro() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("GPS")
                .setMessage("Debe habilitar el GPS")
                .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                        Intent llamadaGPS=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(llamadaGPS);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        textocancel();
                    }
                });

        return builder.create();

    }

    public void textocancel(){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void comprobargps(){
        int locmodo=0;
        String locationProviders;

       /* if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
            try{
                locmodo =Settings.Secure.getInt(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);

            }*/
        //}
    }
}
```

The app does follow the user, where the user is at every moment, but I really don't know where or even how I should check if the GPS is activated

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to check whether GPS is enabled or not..

```
public static boolean isGPSEnabled(Activity activity) {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean gps_enabled = false;
        boolean network_enabled = false;

        try {
            gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.error(Constant.LOGTAG, "gps provider error : " + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.error(Constant.LOGTAG, "network provider error : " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return !(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled);
    }
```

in activity

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

            if(isGPSEnabled(this)){
                  SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                  mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

                  if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
                  }
            }

        }
```

Comment: But... where should I call that method? My main problem is where should I check it, I don't know how to do it so it's always checking if the providers is enabled

Comment: check before mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

Comment: But... Doing that it only checks at the beggining of the app, when I start it, but I need it to be checking all the time